# jQuery table row select set selected value

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a class called .tablesorter-filter and row 5 i am wanting to set the selected value of a select box not a input box. How can I do that?

```
$('.tablesorter-filter').eq(0).val('e'+d.id);
$('.tablesorter-filter').eq(1).val(d.tm_entry);
$('.tablesorter-filter').eq(2).val(d.loc_city);
$('.tablesorter-filter').eq(3).val(d.loc_state);
$('.tablesorter-filter').eq(4).val(d.loc_zip);
$('.tablesorter-filter').eq(5);
```

Comment: Could you provide more information? An example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

#### Important but not the answer:

Please don't use a class selector over and over again. Constantly queriying the DOM like that is bad and it is really really slow. Please do:

```
var $myNode = $('.tablesorter-filter');
$myNode.eq(0).val('e'+d.id);
$myNode.eq(1).val(d.tm_entry);
$myNode.eq(2).val(d.loc_city);
$myNode.eq(3).val(d.loc_state);
$myNode.eq(4).val(d.loc_zip);
$myNode.eq(5);
```

#### The answer:

A select box will work as a normal input so you can just do

```
$("#yourselect").val(yourval)
```

And it should select automatically your value.

So assuming  $myNode.eq(5) is your select, you can just do:

```
 $myNode.eq(5).val(d.selectval);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vApqq/

Comment: +1 As this has the correct answer. But since I assume you are using [this filter widget](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html) for tablesorter, you can also use this method: `$('table').trigger('search', [ 'e'+d.id, d.tm_entry, d.loc_city, d.loc_state, d.loc_zip, d.last_column ]);` - it's the second external search method shown on that page.